# Oracle connection arguments problem when using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I used sqlalchemy to connect to the oracle server from python.
(cx_oracle installation and oracle instant client setup are completed.)

The code I used is as follows:
(I used the ip address instead of the hostname. The ip address is a sample value.)

```
engine = create_engine('oracle://scott:tiger@123.234.345.567:1521/sidname')
q = engine.execute(test_query)
q.fetchone()
```

But I got the error like below.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-24454: client host name is not set
```

I didn't use hostname, but I don't know why this error occurred.
Shouldn't I use the ip address?

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

That error is about the configuration of the machine you are running SQLAlchemy on, not the syntax you are using.  Using an IP address is OK.

Typically Linux users update /etc/hosts and add a hostname for the loopback address.  If you update your question with system information, we can help more.